# Get Windows Service start parameters from HostBuilderContext

Tags: .net, .net-core, windows-services

I am creating a Windows service using the [Microsoft Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service). My code is notionally like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
        {
            if (hostBuilderContext.Configuration["pocket"] == "corner")
            {
                // configure wocket for corner pocket
            }
            else if (hostBuilderContext.Configuration["pocket"] == "side")
            {
                // configure wocket for side pocket
            }
        })
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

I should like to be able to pass in **Start parameters** via the service properties dialog as shown below:

[image: Notional Windows service properties dialog box]

When I hit **Start**, I expect to find a `pocket` value of `corner` in the host builder's `.Configuration` key-value pair collection because it is populated (*among other sources of configuration information*) with the content of `args`. Waesucks, it is not there.

I even interrogated `args` directly just make sure there was not some parsing error that prevented the start parameters from making it into `hostBuilderContext.Properties`. `args` does not contain the start parameters.

I have also tried looing at `hostBuilderContext.Properties`, but it is empty, too.

Is there any way to get the **Start parameters**? I cannot find any code examples online.

Comment: What do you think the `args` in `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` (which are passed from the `String[] args` received in `Main()`) are for?

Comment: @KenWhite, check your premises. There are no contradictions.

Comment: I didn't say there were *contradictions*. I said you receive the `args` (commandline arguments) from `Main`, which your own code passes into `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`, which means that you should be reading `args` to get those arguments instead of `hostBuilderContext.Configuration`. Check your premises.

Comment: @KenWhite, I posted the question because, to my surprise (and apparently yours, too), the start parameters do not show up in `args`. Furthermore, `hostBuilderContext.Configuration` is populated by parsing (among other sources) `args`. If it's in `args`, it will be in `hostBuilderContext.Configuration`.

Comment: @KenWhite, please accept my apologies. Your first comment rubbed me the wrong way, and instead of lowering the temperature in the room, I turned it up with my snide reply. Not golden rule behavior on my part and not the kind of person I want to be. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the parameters will be in args
`string[] args` if you are in the Main method.

otherwise, you can always read them using Environment:

`var cmdArgs =  Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`

I think this is a good example :
https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2022/03/22/windowsservice-2/

Comment: Thank you for the submission. That was my assumption, too, and in my research, I had come across Herr Nagel's article. It turns out that he does not deal with start parameters provided via the service properties page. Additionally, the start parameters do not appear in `args`, `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`, or `hostBuilderContext.Configuration` (which is populated by parsing `args` and other sources of configuration). ‍♂️